# google-app-engine The library "endpoints" is not supported.

Tags: python, google-app-engine, endpoints

I'm attempting to create endpoints for my google-app-engine in Python.  I've followed the directions on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/ and when I attempt to upload I am getting the following message:

> Host: appengine.google.com Error parsing yaml file: the library
>   "endpoints" is not supported   in "guestbook/app.yaml", line 22,
>   column 1

I believe I've got everything configured correctly, can anyone point me in the right direction?  I believe having the library import for "endpoints" is critical for this to function.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
application: xxxxxxx
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: enders.application

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: endpoints
  version: "1.0"

- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"

- name: webapp2
  version: latest

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: which version of SDK you are using?

Comment: Thanks lucemia, I had an old version that was still on my machine.  I removed it and then was able to successfully deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using the most recent version of the AppEngine SDK.  Cloud Endpoints was moved to a library in version 1.8.5.

Answer (score 1):

lucemia pushed me down the right path.  I had two versions of the SDK so I removed the older version and voila, problem solved.